# CENTOS command won't run on startup

Tags: boot, centos, rtorrent

I have `rtorrent` installed and I am trying to run this command so it runs automatically on startup:

```
screen -S rtorrent -d -m su root -c "rtorrent"
```

I added it to: `nano /etc/rc.local`

But nothing seems to happen when I reboot. If I type it in my terminal, it comes up fine without a problem? Why?

Answer (score 1):

/etc/rc.local is used to start services.  Services typically do not have any kind of GUI or require any kind of user interaction. If you are expecting rtorrent to bring up some kind of window automatically, before you log in, that will not happen since rtorrent does not know what DISPLAY or tty to use for the display.

If you want rtorrent to start up automatically when you log in, try putting the rtorrent command into one of your .bash files.  Remember though to check if it is already running if you do not want it to be brought up every single time you start a new terminal window or other app that sources in the .bash files.

Hope this helps.

UPDATE:

From https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bash-Startup-Files.html

> When Bash is invoked as an interactive login shell, or as a
>   non-interactive shell with the --login option, it first reads and
>   executes commands from the file /etc/profile, if that file exists.
>   After reading that file, it looks for ~/.bash_profile, ~/.bash_login,
>   and ~/.profile, in that order, and reads and executes commands from
>   the first one that exists and is readable.

So, if you put your command into your ~/.bash_login file, for example, whenever you log in, whatever is in ~/.bash_login will get executed, including your rtorrent command.

BTW, ~ stands for your home directory, or ${HOME}, in case you did not know that.

Comment: what bash file? I am sorry I am not great with linux but I am learning.